# Convert the summary statistic from psych Package mediate() function to Latex

Tags: r, latex, psych

Is there any possibility to convert the the summary statistic from psych Package mediate() function to Latex?

I tried stargazer, texreg and xtable so far - but without success...

```
#check and install required packages
if (!require("psych")) install.packages("psych")
if (!require("stargazer")) install.packages("stargazer")
if (!require("texreg")) install.packages("texreg")
if (!require("xtable")) install.packages("xtable")

#load required packages
library(psych)
library(stargazer)
library(texreg)
library(xtable)

#data from Preacher and Hayes (2004)
sobel <- structure(list(SATIS = c(-0.59, 1.3, 0.02, 0.01, 0.79, -0.35, 
                                  -0.03, 1.75, -0.8, -1.2, -1.27, 0.7, -1.59, 0.68, -0.39, 1.33, 
                                  -1.59, 1.34, 0.1, 0.05, 0.66, 0.56, 0.85, 0.88, 0.14, -0.72, 
                                  0.84, -1.13, -0.13, 0.2), 
                        THERAPY = structure(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
                                            value.labels = structure(c(1, 0), .Names = c("cognitive", "standard"))), 
                        ATTRIB = c(-1.17, 0.04, 0.58, -0.23, 0.62, -0.26, -0.28, 0.52, 0.34, -0.09, -1.09, 1.05, -1.84, -0.95, 0.15, 0.07, 
                                   -0.1, 2.35, 0.75, 0.49, 0.67, 1.21, 0.31, 1.97, -0.94, 0.11, -0.54, -0.23, 0.05, -1.07)), .Names = c("SATIS", "THERAPY", "ATTRIB"), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame", variable.labels = structure(c("Satisfaction", "Therapy", "Attributional Positivity"), 
                                                                                              .Names = c("SATIS", "THERAPY", "ATTRIB")))


#n.iter set to 50 (instead of default of 5000) for speed of example
res <- mediate(1,2,3,sobel,n.iter=50)  #The example in Preacher and Hayes
res

summary(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this type of model is not supported by any of the main table-making packages. However, it is quite easy to add support for the [`modelsummary` package (disclaimer: I am the author.)](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html) All you need to do is create a function called `tidy.mediate` which returns a data.frame with three columns called: `term`, `estimate`, and `std.error`. Then, you define a function called `glance.mediate` which returns a data.frame with one row and one column for each of the model characteristic you want to include at the bottom of the table.

This will require you to look into your model object (try `str(res)`) a bit to figure out where the information you want is stored, but it’s pretty easy. You’ll find all the details in the “Adding New Models” section of the website: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html

Here’s a minimal example:

```r
library(psych)

library(modelsummary)

res <- mediate(1, 2, 3, sobel, n.iter = 50) # The example in Preacher and Hayes


tidy.mediate <- function(x, ...) {
  out <- data.frame(
    row.names(x$a.reg$beta),
    x$a.reg$beta,
    x$a.reg$se
  )
  colnames(out) <- c("term", "estimate", "std.error")
  out
}

glance.mediate <- function(x, ...) {
  out <- data.frame(nobs = nrow(x$data))
  out
}

modelsummary(res)
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Intercept | -0.354 |
|  | (0.218) |
| THERAPY | 0.819 |
|  | (0.299) |
| Num.Obs. | 30 |

Comment: Thx Vincent! That’s helpful!